# Get value by getProperties in Titanium

Tags: properties, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have two window :

window1 : have an option_dialog width 3 option : 'Video','Image','Document'

```
 var optionsDialogOpts = {
 options:['Video','Image','Document'],
 title:'Type'
 };

var dialog_search_click = Titanium.UI.createOptionDialog(optionsDialogOpts);
dialog_search_click.addEventListener('click',function(e){
//spinner_search_click.setTitle(e.index);
if(e.index==0)
{
//save option select All
Ti.App.Properties.setString('option_dialog','0');
}
if(e.index==1)
{
 Ti.App.Properties.setString('option_dialog','1');
}
if(e.index==2)
{
Ti.App.Properties.setString('option_dialog','2');
}
```

})

window2 : display option that selected in window1..

```
var option=Ti.App.Properties.getString('option_dialog');
Ti.API.info(option);
```

In the first time, option is displayed in window2 is true but when click back to window1 and select other option in option_dialog and go to window 2,it also only display option as the first time ,not change.Can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

This code is right but, I thought one error with this. 
your window1 and window2 both code in one .JS file. so this problem is ocurring.

```
var option=Ti.App.Properties.getString('option_dialog');
```

This line is not update always, it store information once.

You try this type,

add a new Button on Second window and check on Click Event this is working properly.

```
button.addeventListener('click',function(){
   var option=Ti.App.Properties.getString('option_dialog');
   alert("Option :- " + option);

});
```

If, this is working then. I think you can understand, What i want to say.
Cheers.....!